# Curve Global Approximation, Java implementation

Tags: java, android

I need fit a curved line to a set of vertices.  A very promising method for doing this is discussed in the below link, though I'm finding it a bit challenging to implement the algorithm from the discussion.  I was hoping that someone might be aware of an available java implementation of this algorithm?

http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-APP-global.html

Comment: It looks like a Catmull-Rom spline. I wonder why this is never mentioned in the page.

Comment: ^ But doesn't pass directly through the given points.

Comment: I believe that Catmull-Rom spline works by adding additional vertices (via some algorithm I don't understand).  While the curve determined by the algorithm in the link has less control points than the given number of vertices.

Comment: Ah, I get it -- cheers for the explanation :)